# Clear Clipboard on Mac

Tags: macos

I am trying to clear the clipboard using the system command. So I have the following code in my application(written in C on Mac 10.6) -

```
SYSTEM("/bin/echo -n '' | /usr/bin/pbcopy");
```

but the above line does not clear the clip board. Interestingly, if I run the following command in the Terminal, it does clear the clipboard.

```
/bin/echo -n '' | /usr/bin/pbcopy
```

Any idea why System is behaving strangely.

Comment: Are you sure the system call is working at all? Are you checking for errors? Can you try `/bin/echo test > /tmp/test.txt`?

Comment: @Thilo - No I am not checking for errors. Also the system calls like system("/usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en1 on") - which is the line above this is working.

Comment: Why just C, why not write Obj-C and use C inside it. This will give you all of the Cocoa Mac goodness? Maybe I'm missing something, but I believe you can write straight C inside Obj-C

Comment: Also, the function is called "system", not "SYSTEM". C is case-sensitive.

Comment: try `system("/usr/bin/pbcopy < /dev/null")`

Answer (score 2):

You're doing way too much work.  There's no need to fork a shell and two more processes to do this:

```
[[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] clearContents];
```

Comment: His program is written in C, though.

Comment: Then link to the Carbon library and call PasteboardClear().